# Problem with Php password on a flash blog

Tags: php, flash, blogs

I recently purchased a flash blog on Flashcomponents.net : http://www.flashcomponents.net/component/advanced_xml_flash_blog_with_cms_and_rating_system.html
There is the blog and the blog "editor", for wich you have to log in. The password is defined in a Php file named 'admin.php'.
The problem is that, whatever password I type, I never managed to log in..

Here is the code of 'admin.php' :

```
<?php

$password = "admin";

if($_POST['un'] == $password){
    print "t";
}else{
    print "Access denied";
}

?>
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: On a completely other note, for SEO an all-flash website is going to be awful. None of the content can be read by google in context. 

If you care about search engines, you might want to reconsider using it.

Answer (score 2):

You should also not store the password like that. At the very least, run it through MD5:

```
$password = "yourmd5edpasshere";

if(md5($_POST['un']) == $password){
    print "t";
}else{
    die('Access denied');
}
```

However, due to the fact that the variable is called 'un', and is "admin", I'd be inclined to think that it was a username and not a password.

If this is indicative of the quality of the rest of the program, (and for a "flash blog" I wouldn't be surprised) then your money was wasted

Answer (score 0):

Add before the `if` line: `print_r($_POST);` to make sure the data you think is being posted is being posted.